# My form Verification and Validation with JS is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to verify and validate a form in HTML, and insert messages in Front if necessary ("eg.Pseudo/Username not long enough"), which will serve as a "new user" form for a website.
I want to start by understanding my mistake for the "Pseudo" verification and validation.

I currently have the following in HTML:

```
<form id="formNouveau" onsubmit="return valideForm2()">
            <div>
                <div id="msgPseudo"></div>
                <label for="pseudo">Pseudo</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="msgEmail"></div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <br>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="msgPass"></div>
                <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="*******" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="msgPassRep"></div>
                <label for="passwordRepeat">Repeat your password</label>
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="passwordRepeat" id="passwordRepeat" placeholder="*******" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create an account">
            </div>
        </form>
```

and the following in JS (focusing on the pseudo validation):

```
function valideForm(){
  var valPseudo = document.getElementById("pseudo").value;
  var msgPseudo = document.getElementById("msgPseudo");

function valPseudo(text)
    let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    let numbers = '0123456789'
    let letterCount = 0
    let numberCount = 0
    for (let character of text.toLowerCase()) {
      if (letters.includes(character))
        ++letterCount
      else if (numbers.includes(character))
        ++numberCount
      else
        return false //A non [a-zA-Z0-9] character was present
    }

  if (valPseudo == "")
    alert ("Please write a pseudo");
 if (letterCount + numberCount > 40)
    alert ("Pseudo is too long") //The name is too long
if (letterCount + numberCount < 5)
    alert ("Pseudo is too short") //The name is too short
  if (letterCount < 1)
    alert ("one letter needed at least") //There aren't enough [a-zA-Z] characters
  if (numberCount < 1)
    alert ("one number needed at least") //There aren't enough [0-9] characters

  return 0 //Everything is okay!
}

  
}
```

What do you think?

Thank you!

Comment: Your function names dont match. You definied it as valideForm but you are trying to call it valideForm2.

Comment: What doesnt work? Where is it failing?

Comment: I changed both ids in HTML and JS to « ValidForm ». But the form still validates without checking the pseudo requirements. I am not sure if the fonction valPseudo(text) is correct by its name, link or formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix of variable names in the function and a sub function with incorrect syntax. You're not preventing the form from submitting. Fixed both and it works:

```js
function valideForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var valPseudo = document.getElementById("pseudo").value;
  var msgPseudo = document.getElementById("msgPseudo");

  let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  let numbers = '0123456789'
  let letterCount = 0
  let numberCount = 0
  for (let character of valPseudo.toLowerCase()) {
    if (letters.includes(character))
      ++letterCount
    else if (numbers.includes(character))
      ++numberCount
    else
      return false //A non [a-zA-Z0-9] character was present
  }

  if (valPseudo == "")
    alert("Please write a pseudo");
  if (letterCount + numberCount > 40)
    alert("Pseudo is too long") //The name is too long
  if (letterCount + numberCount < 5)
    alert("Pseudo is too short") //The name is too short
  if (letterCount < 1)
    alert("one letter needed at least") //There aren't enough [a-zA-Z] characters
  if (numberCount < 1)
    alert("one number needed at least") //There aren't enough [0-9] characters

  return 0 //Everything is okay!
}

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', valideForm);
```

```html
<form id="formNouveau">
  <div>
    <div id="msgPseudo"></div>
    <label for="pseudo">Pseudo</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="msgEmail"></div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="msgPass"></div>
    <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="*******" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="msgPassRep"></div>
    <label for="passwordRepeat">Repeat your password</label>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="passwordRepeat" id="passwordRepeat" placeholder="*******" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create an account">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function valideForm2(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var valPseudo = document.getElementById("pseudo").value;
  var msgPseudo = document.getElementById("msgPseudo");

  console.log(valPseudo);

  function validate(text) {
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    let numbers = "0123456789";
    let letterCount = 0;
    let numberCount = 0;
    for (let character of text.toLowerCase()) {
      if (letters.includes(character)) ++letterCount;
      else if (numbers.includes(character)) ++numberCount;
      else return false; //A non [a-zA-Z0-9] character was present
    }

    if (text == "") alert("Please write a pseudo");
    if (letterCount + numberCount > 40) alert("Pseudo is too long"); //The name is too long
    if (letterCount + numberCount < 5) alert("Pseudo is too short"); //The name is too short
    if (letterCount < 1) alert("one letter needed at least"); //There aren't enough [a-zA-Z] characters
    if (numberCount < 1) alert("one number needed at least"); //There aren't enough [0-9] characters

    return 0; //Everything is okay!
  }

  validate(valPseudo);
}

const form = document.getElementById("formNouveau");
form.addEventListener("submit", valideForm2);
```

Try this JS code instead, it has the same functionality but has some modifications, the main problem was regarded to e.preventDefault() which forces page not to reload. Moreover you had some little bugs. For more information on preventDefault you can visit link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I also changed name of inner function as it had conflict with the variable you declared earlier.

Comment: I think onSubmit attribute of the form also is not neccessary any more.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off testing the input against a REGEX expression rather than testing for each failure case...

There a numerous REGEX testers and cheat-sheets online for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have tried a lot of them, but couldn't find one that worked